# update query with optional parameres

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i am trying to update rows with optional parameters, but i am getting error with below query.

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("UPDATE Visit visits SET "
        + " visits.approvalStatus is null OR visits.approvalStatus = :approvalStatus "
        + " , visits.declineReason is null OR visits.declineReason =:declineReason "
        + " WHERE visits.visitId in :visitIds ")
public int patchUpdate(@Param("approvalStatus") String approvalStatus,
        @Param("declineReason") String declineReason, @Param("visitIds") List<Integer> visitIds);
```

error logs :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting EQ, found 'is' near line 1, column 69 [UPDATE com.quest.vms.entity.Visit visits SET  visits.approvalStatus is null OR visits.approvalStatus = :approvalStatus  WHERE visits.visitId in :visitIds ]
```

Edited to add info : here i want to update a particular field when new data is not null, otherwise that parameter should be ignored.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is your intention here in this query ? Are you trying to update approvalStatus if it is not null ?

Comment: yes @Shawrup , i am updating field only when it is not null, i have some other fields to add in this query

Comment: _i am updating field only when it is not null_ did you mean existing approvalStatus is not null or new data is not null ?

Comment: when new data is not null

Comment: Maybe adding `and :approvalStatus  is not null` in `where` condition is enough

Comment: I tried this, but its persisting approvalStatus as null in DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the `UPDATE` query, the part to set a field value is missing.

Possibly a query using `COALESCE` function (or a native query using functions such as `IsNull`, `NullIf`, `NVL`) could be helpful:

```java
@Query("UPDATE Visit visits SET "
     + "visits.approvalStatus = COALESCE(:approvalStatus, approvalStatus) "
     + "visits.declineReason = COALESCE(:declineReason, declineReason) "
     + " WHERE visits.visitId in :visitIds")
public int patchUpdate(
    @Param("approvalStatus") String approvalStatus,
    @Param("declineReason") String declineReason, 
    @Param("visitIds") List<Integer> visitIds
);
```

Or using similar `CASE` statement

```java
@Query("UPDATE Visit visits SET "
     + "visits.approvalStatus = (CASE :approvalStatus WHEN NULL THEN approvalStatus ELSE :approvalStatus END) "
     + "visits.declineReason = (CASE :declineReason WHEN NULL THEN declineReason ELSE :declineReason END) "
     + " WHERE visits.visitId in :visitIds")
public int patchUpdate(
    @Param("approvalStatus") String approvalStatus,
    @Param("declineReason") String declineReason, 
    @Param("visitIds") List<Integer> visitIds
);
```

Comment: i want to update only when incoming param value is not null, otherwise it should be ignored

Comment: it was not accurate answer, but was the most helpful (using CASE) in finding solution. Thanks

Comment: One more question: what if my optional param is null. how can i validate null for incoming boolean param value?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.. You could be using `Boolean` wrapper instead of primitive `boolean` for the input parameter.

Answer (score 3):

is null is used for checking the field.
For setting column on the basis of condition you can use:

```
UPDATE Visit visits SET "
        + "  visits.approvalStatus = CASE "
        + " WHEN visits.visitId in :visitIds THEN :approvalStatus "
        + " ELSE NULL "
        + " END"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a case condition while setting data like

```
UPDATE 
    Visit visits 
SET 
    visits.approvalStatus = (
        case 
            when :approvalStatus is null 
            then visits.approvalStatus 
            else :approvalStatus 
        end
    ),
    visits.declineReason = (
        case 
            when :declineReason is null 
            then visits.declineReason 
            else :declineReason 
        end
    ),
 WHERE visits.visitId in :visitIds
```

If passed value is null, you set the value you have in db, otherwhile set the passed value.